# Memberwise Initialization

Tags: c++, member-initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ initialization lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589237/c-initialization-lists)

What is the difference between member-wise initialization and direct initialization in a class?
What is the difference between the two constructors defined in the class?

```
class A
{
    public:
    int x;
    int y;
    A(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b)
    {}

    A(int a, int b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The theoretical answers have been given by other members.

Pragmatically, member-wise initialization is used in these cases :

- You have a **reference attribute** (`MyClass & mMyClass`) in your class. You need to do a member-wise initialization, otherwise, it doesn't compile.
- You have a **constant attribute** in you class (`const MyClass mMyClass`). You also need to do a member-wise initialization, otherwise, it doesn't compile.
- You have an **attribute with no default constructor** in your class (`MyClass mMyClass` with no constructor `MyClass::MyClass()`). You also need to do a member-wise initialization, otherwise, it doesn't compile.
- You have a **monstruously large attribute** object (`MyClass mMyClass` and `sizeof(MyClass) = 1000000000`). With member-wise initialization, you build it only once. With direct initialization in the constructor, it is built twice.

Comment: This was the kind of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

First one uses **initialization** and second one does NOT use initialization, it uses **assignment**. In the second one, the members `x` and `y` are default-initialized first (with *zero*), and then they're assigned with `a` and `b` respectively.

Also note that in the second one, members are default initialized **only if** the *types* of members are having *non-trivial* default constructor. Otherwise, there is no initialization (as @James noted in the comment).

Now see this topic to know:

- [What is a non-trivial constructor in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899223/what-is-a-non-trivial-constructor-in-c)

Comment: +1.  Although for "int" members the effect is the same.

Comment: In the second, there is only default initialization for types with a non-trivial default constructor.  Otherwise, there is no initialization.

Comment: @James: In this example, the types of `x` and `y` is `int`, hence its default-initialization. But your comment makes it more complete. Let me add it to my answer.

Comment: @Nawaz In this example, the types are `int`, which is a POD, so there is no initialization.  (But you got it right in the modification of your response.)