# What does {error C2338: (boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value)} mean for boost::lockfree::queue ? What am I missing here?

Tags: c++, boost, queue

I have a struct `MyClass` inside another class `MyOuterClass` I am trying to put into a boost::lockfree::queue. My structure looks like below

```
struct MyClass
{
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass(const string& topic, const string& multicastChannel, const string& netInterface, MyOuterClass::MY_COMMAND_ENUM command, MyOuterClass::CallbackType callback)
    :topic(topic), multicastChannel(multicastChannel), netInterface(netInterface), command(command), callback(callback) {}

    MyClass(const MyClass& src)
    :topic(src.topic), multicastChannel(src.multicastChannel), netInterface(src.netInterface), command(src.command), callback(src.callback) {}
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& src)
    {
        topic = src.topic;
        multicastChannel = src.multicastChannel;
        netInterface = src.netInterface;
        command = src.command;
        callback = src.callback;
    }

    ~MyClass(){}

    string topic;
    string multicastChannel;
    string netInterface;
    MyOuterClass::MY_COMMAND_ENUM command;
    MyOuterClass::CallbackType callback;
};
```

My outer class has a public member variable `boost::lockfree::queue<MyClass> m_commandQueue;` which throws the following error when I try to compile.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MDServices, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 6/10/2013 4:41:00 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "x64\Debug\MDServices.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  MyOuterClass.cpp
1>C:\local\boost_1_53_0\boost/lockfree/queue.hpp(79): error C2338: (boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value)
1>          src\MyOuterClass.cpp(70) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::lockfree::queue<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=MDServices::MyClass
1>          ]
1>C:\local\boost_1_53_0\boost/lockfree/queue.hpp(83): error C2338: (boost::has_trivial_assign<T>::value)
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:03.38
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I checked the thread [/boost/lockfree/queue.hpp: error: static assertion failed: (boost::has_trivial_destructor<T>::value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468278/boost-lockfree-queue-hpp-error-static-assertion-failed-boosthas-trivial-d/15468325#15468325) however I am still unable to compile. What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Chinmay

Comment: Your linked question exactly answers your question: You can't define your own destructor or copy assignment operator.

Comment: `trivial` means you do not define it yourself.

Comment: Your `string` members might also prevent you from storing your class in the queue as it is non-trivial.

Comment: @MarkB @Jesse - I tried without defining my own destructor and copy assignment operator. I still get the same error. That is when I searched for the link I have posted and wrote my own copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor. The other thread says the 'trivial' requirement is recursive. Could the use of `std::string` class causing the issue?

Comment: @JesseGood - Thanks for conforming that. Is there a way to get around that? Or do I have to use the regular queue with locks?

Comment: @ChinmayNerurkar: You could use pointers. push on the pointers with `new` and then `delete` when popping.

Comment: @JesseGood - Thanks. That works well for me. I am going to take that as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per JesseGood's comments on my question, the issue was caused due to the use of `std::string` in `MyClass` which is non-trivial. The solution was to store pointers to `MyClass` in my `boost::lockfree::queue` instead of `MyClass` objects directly.