# how to put std::string into boost::lockfree::queue (or alternative)?

Tags: c++, boost, queue, stdstring, lock-free

I'm trying to put `std::string`s into `boost::lockfree::queue`s so that my threads can update each other with new data.

When I try to use `boost::lockfree::queue<std::string> updated_data;`, `g++` says :

> In instantiation of 'class boost::lockfree::queue >':
>
> error: static assertion failed: (boost::has_trivial_destructor::value)
>
> error: static assertion failed: (boost::has_trivial_assign::value)

I've been [shown generally what these errors mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468278/boost-lockfree-queue-hpp-error-static-assertion-failed-boosthas-trivial-d), but I have no hope of ever fixing this myself, as I'm almost brand new to c++.

Is there an alternative way to pass text data between threads with `lockfree`?  If not, please show me how to put `std::string` into a `boost::lockfree::queue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put raw pointers in the queue, the old `std::strings` will be leaked, since there is no way to free them when they are no longer needed. This is because there is no way to free the objects in a thread-safe way without taking a lock (other than some tricks like hazard pointers, which `boost::lockfree::queue` does not use)

For technical reasons I do not really understand, the `boost::lockfree::queue` requires a trivial assignment operator and a trivial destructor, which means that your object cannot be nor contain any data type that must free memory in its destructor, like `std::string`.

Comment: This is not quite true: you can put raw pointers in the queue and free them when you pop the pointer. eg `queue->consume_all([](std::string* str) { do_something(str); delete str; });`

Answer (score 11):

The `boost::lockfree::queue` documentation clearly states the the contained itemm must have a trivial copy assignment and destructor, which `std::string` doesn't have.

If you have a single producer and a single consumer you can use `spsc_queue` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) which requires only default constructability and copyability.

If you have multiple producers or consumers you're going to be stuck with a normal locking queue (or a custom string that doesn't use dynamic allocation).

Comment: Thanks, great heads up on the spsc_queue!

Answer (score 8):

> I have no hope of ever fixing this myself, as I'm almost brand new to c++.

Then I have to wonder why you're messing with things like lockfree queues.

> Is there an alternative way to pass text data between threads with `lockfree`?

Yes, you could just store a `std::string*` pointer to the data in the queue, because a pointer is a trivial type and so is allowed in the queue. Equivalently, you could store a `reference_wrapper<std::string>`. The problem with that is you need to store the strings somewhere else, in order to be able to point to them, so now all you've done is move the problem to somewhere else (e.g. you could maintain a list of strings in each thread, and store pointers to the externally-managed string in the lock-free queue, but you don't know when it's safe to remove a `string` from the per-thread list so it grows and grows.)

I would suggest you use a simple `std::queue<std::string>` and do your own synchronisation with a `boost::mutex` and `boost::condition_variable`, or find an existing implementation of a thread-safe (not lock-free!) queue.

Comment: This gets +1 because I didn't even consider storing raw pointers in the queue.

Comment: Do what already, store raw pointers?  Where would it put the actual objects?  It's generally bad practice to put unmanaged raw pointers in containers, it's too easy to leak memory

Comment: Well there you go then, you've solved the problem, now it's just a [simple matter of programming](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/SMOP.html) ;)

Comment: WARNING: You WILL leak memory unless you use some trick like hazard pointers (no way to free the old std::strings)

Comment: @Gracchus, I'm glad you have been convinced it's not so easy :)