# dynamically-sized text object with a copy constructor, a trivial assignment operator, and a trivial destructor

Tags: c++, text, c++11, static-libraries, dynamic-sizing

I've [been shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17452707/1382306) that a `std::string` cannot be inserted into a `boost::lockfree::queue`.

`boost::lockfree::queue` is too valuable to abandon, so I think I could use very large, fixed length `char`s to pass the data according to the [requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html) (assuming that even satifies since I'm having trouble learning about how to satisfy these requirements), but that will eat up memory if I want large messages.

Does a dynamically-sized text object with a copy constructor, a trivial assignment operator, and a trivial destructor exist?  If so, where?  If not, please outline how to manifest one.

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic string?  Surely, once it's in the queue you don't need to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamically-size type with a trivial copy ctor/dtor is not possible. There are two solutions to your problem, use a fixed sized type, or store pointers in the queue:

```
boost::lockfree::queue<std::string*> queue(some_size);
// push on via new
queue.push(new std::string("blah"));
// pop and delete
std::string* ptr;
if(queue.pop(ptr))
{
   delete ptr;
}
```

Comment: @Gracchus: `the pointer cannot be fully released`, can you provide a detailed explanation?

Answer (score 1):

> Does a dynamically-sized text object with a copy constructor, a trivial assignment operator, and a trivial destructor exist?

Dynamically sized, no. For something to have a trivial destructor, it requires that the destructor of the object is implicit (or defaulted), and any non-static member objects also have implicit (or defaulted) destructors. Since anything that is dynamically allocated will require a `delete []` somewhere along the line in a destructor, you cannot have this constraint satisfied.

To expand upon the above, consider a (very cut down) example of what happens in `std::string`:

```
namespace std
{
    // Ignoring templates and std::basic_string for simplicity
    class string 
    {
    private:
        char* internal_;
        // Other fields

    public:
        string(const char* str)
          : internal_(new char[strlen(str) + 1])
        { }

    };
}
```

Consider what would happen if we left the destructor as default: it would destroy the stack-allocated `char *` (that is, the pointer **itself**, not what it **points to**). This would cause a memory leak, as we now have allocated space that has no references and hence can never be freed. So we need to declare a destructor:

```
~string()
{
    delete[] internal_;
}
```

However, by doing this, the destructor becomes user-defined and is therefore non-trivial.

This will be a problem with anything that is dynamically allocated. Note that we cannot fix this by using something like a `shared_ptr` or a `vector<char>` as a member variable; even though they may be stack allocated in our class, underneath, they are simply taking care of the memory management for us: somewhere along the line with these, there is a `new []` and corresponding `delete []`, hence they will have non-trivial destructors.

To satisfy this, you'll need to use a stack allocated `char` array. That means no dynamic allocation, and therefore a fixed size.

Comment: @Gracchus Expanded. Hopefully that answers your question more fully.