# How to get a string pointer's value?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, queue, lock-free

I am trying to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18710362/1382306) to pass strings through boost::lockfree::queues.

It looks like it does work, but when I try to cout the pointer after popping it off the queue, it only reads out a memory address.

I have looked everywhere for a solution, but I strangely can't find one.

How can I get the contents of `ptr` below?

```
boost::lockfree::queue<std::string*> queue(some_size);
// push on via new
queue.push(new std::string("blah"));
// pop and delete
std::string* ptr;
if(queue.pop(ptr))
{
   std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
   delete ptr;
}
```

Result:

```
0x7f41fc000950
```

Comment: Am I being dumb or would `std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;` suffice?

Comment: @Gracchus Notice that I’ve deleted my comment. It was a brain fart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get at contents of the string, just dereference the pointer, duh. ;-)

```
std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
```