# Are there any situations where a class destructor would not be called for a class when the scope ends?

Tags: c++

Are there any situations where a class destructor would *not* be called for a class when it leaves the scope?

Comment: What do you mean by *when being cleaned up*?  Do you mean when the scope ends?  When you throw an exception?

Comment: @NathanOliver When the scope ends

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741698/is-c-compiler-allowed-to-optimize-out-unreferenced-local-objects

Comment: Terminating the program. Also `longjmp()`.

Comment: Placement new...

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming that the object here is plain value (not member of union or allocated in heap so cannot be leaked), I can imagine only one situation: ending a process by something like [std::terminate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate).

It can be called directly or called in situations when uncatched exception occurs in `noexcept` method.

It may be not "correct" to call this situation an "end of the scope" because you never actually return from std::terminate. However, from practical point of view this is probably exact situation which you want to know about.