# Is an empty constructor with initializer list considered trivial?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Is the following constructor considered trivial?

```
struct A
{
    A() : a(nullptr) {}
private:
    int* a;
};
```

These [examples](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) makes me a little confused. With c++11 this should also be possible:

```
struct A
{
private:
    int* a{nullptr};
};
```

and `a` should be properly initialized to `nullptr`. Here I did not define the constructor, but it should have the same form as the first implementation. Is either of these classes considered trivial?

The purpose of me asking is if I can expect move/copy constructors and assignment operators being automatically generated.

Comment: You can check by `static_assert`ing with `std::is_trivial`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a non-trivial constructor in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899223/what-is-a-non-trivial-constructor-in-c)

Comment: auto generation of those other functions has nothing to do with whether the constructor is trivial

Comment: I don't think I agree with the duplication as it does not answer the question fully. Will the compiler generate other constructors in the second case?

Comment: "*The purpose of me asking is if I can expect move/copy constructors and assignment operators being automatically generated.*" It should be noted that the presence or absence of a trivial default constructor has nothing to do with move/copy constructors/operators being generated.

Comment: @NicolBolas Do you mean in the sense that they can be explicitly generated by `A(const A&) = default;`, or is there another reason? I thought they were implicitly generated if the default constructor was.

Comment: @pingul: No, I mean in every sense. The triviality of the default constructor has no bearing on the compiler-generated move/copy constructors/operators or the destructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the following constructor considered trivial?

```
A() : a(nullptr) {}
```

No, because it is user-defined.

```
struct A
{
private:
    int* a{nullptr};
};
```

No, because it has brace initializer for a non-static member.

According to the standard (emphasis mine):

> **12.1 Constructors**
> ....
>
> A default constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X` that can be called without an argument. If
>   there is no user-declared constructor for class `X`, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.40).
> ....
>
> A default constructor is trivial ***if it is not user-provided*** and if:
> ....
>   — ***no non-static data member of its class has a brace-or-equal-initializer***, and
> ....
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is non-trivial.

---

> The purpose of me asking is if I can expect move/copy constructors and assignment operators being automatically generated.

As **@M.M** and **@NicolBolas** commented, generation of these constructors and operators are not impacted by existence of the trivial constructor.

The rules are a bit complicated and not very consistent.

The **copy constructor** is generated only if there is no explicitly declared one. (And it is deleted if the move constructor or the move assignment operator is declared.)

Similarly, the **copy assignment operator** is generated only if there is no explicitly declared one. (And again, it is deleted if the move constructor or the move assignment operator is declared.)

The **move constructor** is generated only if there are no explicitly declared move constructor, move operator, copy constructor, copy assignment and destructor.

The same rule is for the **move assignment operator**.

Comment: Another weird caveat is that a constructor that is declared inline and then = default in the .cpp file, is still not considered trivial. I guess technically it is "user declared" at that point, but it's a weird edge case and weird they decided to say "user declared" and not "user defined".