# std::atomic for built-in types - non-lock-free vs. trivial destructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, atomic, lock-free

Looking at [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) and it's default specializations I read:

> These specializations have standard layout, *trivial default constructors*, and *trivial destructors*.

I also read for [`is_lock_free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/is_lock_free):

> All atomic types except for `std::atomic_flag` *may be implemented using
>   mutexes* or other locking operations, rather than using the lock-free
>   atomic CPU instructions. Atomic types are also allowed to be sometimes
>   lock-free, e.g. if only aligned memory accesses are naturally atomic
>   on a given architecture, misaligned objects of the same type have to
>   use locks.

Now here's the catch that I don't get:

How can any `atomic` type where the Standard prescribes *trivial ctor/dtor* ever be using any kind of mutex -- all mutexes I ever came across required *non*-trivial initialization.

This leads to the following questions:

- Do major platforms provide any locking operation (like a mutex) that is "initalization free" per object. (That would be the "other locking operations".)
- Is there any known implementation today for default `std::atomic` specializations that isn't lock free (and still fulfills the *trivial ctor/dtor* requirement)?
- Am I simply confusing something here? :-)

It seems to me that even the simplest spin lock (see [`atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag)) needs non-trivial initialization, so I fail to see how this could be implemented.

Disclaimer: Purely out of academic interest, as this kinda jumped out on me while reading these docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution: if an atomic operation uses a lock but has a trivial constructor and destructor, the mutex may be a global mutex shared between many atomic values.

This, I believe, is the case that the standard authors were allowing.  It is possible to use trivial constructors and destructors for mutexes with static duration on some common platforms (such as POSIX).

```
// This is copied plain C here, not C++
// So nothing fancy
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_mutex_t my_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

If the `std::atomic` default constructors were permitted to be non-trivial, then it would be difficult to use them during initialization.

```
std::atomic<int> my_flag;
```

Because `my_flag`has a *trivial* constructor, it is static-initialized.  Static initialization happens before dynamic initialization.  So you can be sure that all the global `std::atomic` variables are initialized before your constructors run.

Comment: Ha! Yes, it seems this would fulfill the standard requirements. Seems kinda insane for most real world use cases though!

Comment: Yes, it seems insane.  But people want to write C++ code that runs on insane architectures, and the standards authors oblige.

Comment: Wrt. your edit: The code isn't *trivial* initalization, since it sets the (static) object to a value. (?) Of course, any object using this wouldn't need to do anything so could have a trivial ctor.

Comment: What I find rather odd is to allow locking implementations (OK, so what) but *require* trivial construction/destruction. For an architecture where I'd need a mutex to implement `std::atomic_int` it would still seem better to me to have this type to have non-trivial initialization (because it has to carry a mutex) that to have *all* `atomic_int` objects share the same mutex. I guess it's a design question, so whatever.

Comment: @MartinBa - there are all kinds of possibilities between the extremes of using a single mutex and having each atomic object hold its own mutex. For example, there could be a double handful of mutexes shared between various atomic objects.

Comment: @MartinBa: I've not heard the term "trivial initialization" before.  This is aggregate initialization for a class with a trivial constructor.  In implementation terms, this means that the initialization can be done by the executable loader.  In the language of the C++ standard, this means that static atomic values can be constant-initialized, which means that they are guaranteed to be initialized before any dynamic-initialized values.

Comment: @MartinBa: Using a nontrivial constructor would mean that the initialization of any top-level static atomic variables would be "indeterminately sequenced" and that would be especially problematic for code that needs atomic synchronization during initialization.  This is a fairly common situation, so it makes sense that the standard committee would require a trivial constructor/destructor, especially since common platforms would have a trivial constructor/destructor anyway.

Comment: @MartinBa: This is how it works in practice: g++ and clang for the x86-64 System V ABI have `sizeof(std::atomic<foo>) == sizeof(foo)` in every case I've looked at, so there's no room for a per-object lock.  Apparently this is required by the standard's `trivial constructor` wording which precludes using even a const-initialized spinlock (which would avoid any "indeterminately sequenced" / [the static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Comment: @Dietrich: According to my reading [of this Q&A, esp. the quote from the C++11 standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899223/what-is-a-non-trivial-constructor-in-c), a *trivial* constructor can't even set a compile-time-constant value, like you're showing for the C `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` case.  It has to be non-user-supplied, and the non-static data members must not have initializers.  So requiring it to be trivial is much stronger than just requiring it not be dynamic, at least for objects with static storage duration.

Comment: @MartinBa: I haven't looked inside g++'s library implementations of the helper-functions it calls for non-lock-free loads/stores/read-modify-write operations.  (e.g. see [g++6.3 for x86-64 output on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/wiLBn6)).  **It's *possible* that it uses separate locks for separate objects, maybe even with a hash table of locks indexed by object address.**  If it really does use one global shared lock to protect all objects, that would be horrible for concurrency with multiple objects.

Comment: @PeterCordes: There are two different concepts here which we should be careful to keep separate.  One is *aggregate initialization* and another is *trivial constructor.*  Your claim that a trivial constructor cannot even set compile-time constant values is correct, but that is not what is happening here.  The members are being initialized by *aggregate initialization* which is something that is only possible because the type has a trivial constructor.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization if you are curious (or read the standard).

Comment: @DietrichEpp: oh, I wasn't trying to claim that the pthreads C code was using any kind of constructor.  C++ `std::atomic<>` doesn't require an aggregate initializer to work correctly, and the only other option for initializing locks stored inside the object would be a non-trivial constructor (which is ruled out).