# How to achieve vector swizzling in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, glsl, mingw

```
struct vec2
{
    union
    {
        struct { float x, y; };
        struct { float r, g; };
        struct { float s, t; };
    };
    vec2() {}
    vec2(float a, float b) : x(a), y(b) {}
};
struct vec3
{
    union
    {
        struct { float x, y, z; };
        struct { float r, g, b; };
        struct { float s, t, p; };
        // Here is the problem with g++.
        struct { vec2 xy; float z; };
        struct { float x; vec2 yz; };
    };
    vec3() {}
    vec3(float a, float b, float c) : x(a), y(b), z(c) {}
};
```

The code above compiles and works as expected in Visual Studio and so I can use it like

```
vec3 v1(1.f, 2.f, 3.f);
vec2 v2 = v1.yz; // (2, 3)
```

**Not** in g++ (MinGW).

```
src/main.cpp:22:23: error: member 'vec2 vec3::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::xy' with constructor not allowed in anonymous aggregate
src/main.cpp:22:33: error: redeclaration of 'float vec3::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::z'
src/main.cpp:18:30: note: previous declaration 'float vec3::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::z'
src/main.cpp:23:32: error: member 'vec2 vec3::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::yz' with constructor not allowed in anonymous aggregate
src/main.cpp:23:24: error: redeclaration of 'float vec3::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::x'
src/main.cpp:18:24: note: previous declaration 'float vec3::<unnamed union>::<unnamed struct>::x'
```

I think I shouldn't be doing it like that in the first place. Any Ideas?

**Edit:** After reading a lot of articles and exploring open-source projects, I started to get how vector swizzling should be like and posted the solution below, still waiting for better answers though.

> **Edit 2:** All `vec*` members ***must be accessed only from the parent*** like the **GLM** library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I've found the solution myself using only the C++ Standards.
No *command-lines* neither using *compiler-specific* code.

So this is my new and simple implementation

```
template<unsigned int I>
struct scalar_swizzle
{
    float v[1];
    float &operator=(const float x)
    {
        v[I] = x;
        return v[I];
    }
    operator float() const
    {
        return v[I];
    }
    float operator++(int)
    {
        return v[I]++;
    }
    float operator++()
    {
        return ++v[I];
    }
    float operator--(int)
    {
        return v[I]--;
    }
    float operator--()
    {
        return --v[I];
    }
};
// We use a vec_type in a template instead of forward declartions to prevent erros in some compilers.
template<typename vec_type, unsigned int A, unsigned int B>
struct vec2_swizzle
{
    float d[2];
    vec_type operator=(const vec_type& vec)
    {
        return vec_type(d[A] = vec.x, d[B] = vec.y);
    }
    operator vec_type()
    {
        return vec_type(d[A], d[B]);
    }
};
struct vec2
{
    union
    {
        float d[2];
        scalar_swizzle<0> x, r, s;
        scalar_swizzle<1> y, g, t;
        vec2_swizzle<vec2, 0, 0> xx;
        vec2_swizzle<vec2, 1, 1> yy;
    };
    vec2() {}
    vec2(float all)
    {
        x = y = all;
    }
    vec2(float a, float b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
};
/* Debugging */
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, vec2 vec)
{
    os << "(" << vec.x << ", " << vec.y << ")";
    return os;
}
template<typename vec_type, unsigned int A, unsigned int B, unsigned int C>
struct vec3_swizzle
{
    float d[3];
    vec_type operator=(const vec_type& vec)
    {
        return vec_type(d[A] = vec.x, d[B] = vec.y, d[C] = vec.z);
    }
    operator vec_type()
    {
        return vec_type(d[A], d[B], d[C]);
    }
};
struct vec3
{
    union
    {
        float d[3];
        scalar_swizzle<0> x, r, s;
        scalar_swizzle<1> y, g, t;
        scalar_swizzle<2> z, b, p;
        vec2_swizzle<vec2, 0, 1> xy;
        vec2_swizzle<vec2, 1, 2> yz;
        vec3_swizzle<vec3, 0, 1, 2> xyz;
        vec3_swizzle<vec3, 2, 1, 0> zyx;
    };
    vec3() {}
    vec3(float all)
    {
        x = y = z = all;
    }
    vec3(float a, float b, float c)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
        z = c;
    }
};
/* Debugging */
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, vec3 vec)
{
    os << "(" << vec.x << ", " << vec.y << ", " << vec.z << ")";
    return os;
}
```

Of course, you can add/create more swizzlings. Now with a little test.

```
int main()
{
    vec3 v0(10, 20, 30);
    std::cout << v0.zyx << std::endl;
    vec2 c(-5, -5);
    v0.xy = c;
    vec2 v1(v0.yz);
    std::cout << v0 << std::endl;
    std::cout << v1 << std::endl;
    vec3 v(50, 60, 70);
    vec2 d = v.yz;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    float f = d.x * d.y;
    std::cout << f << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Out:**

```
(30, 20, 10)
(-5, -5, 30)
(-5, 30)
(60, 70)
4200
```

You can print the vectors for debugging with `std::cout` if you're not using an **IDE** as I did in gcc.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer still uses the anonymous struct extension. It [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/g/N4RFLp) with [`-pedantic-errors`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options).

Comment: That's actually easy to fix by creating a `vec1_swizzle`.

Comment: By the way, for sure ***it won't compile*** because `-pedantic-errors` flag is used to convert `-pedantic` warnings to errors.

Comment: @xskxzr forgot to edit my answer sooner... Now it works with `-pedantic-errors`. :D

Comment: You violate the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/5376789).

Comment: I mean this expression: `*(vec_type*)this`. In fact, unions [are also dangerous in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203/5376789), which is different from that in C.

Comment: In networking, we **always** cast `sockaddr_in*` to `sockaddr*` and vice versa. Won't that break it too? updated answer by the way.

Comment: "In networking, we always cast sockaddr_in* to sockaddr* and vice versa." [That's due to historical reasons and is a bad habit nowadays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42190913/5376789).

Answer (score 6):

First, anonymous struct is [a feature from C11](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html), and is [not allowed by C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253878/why-does-c-disallow-anonymous-structs), so it does not support class members with constructors (not a C struct). To write portable C++ code, you should avoid anonymous struct:

```
struct vec2 // use C++ style struct declaration
{
// struct is public by default
    union
    {
        struct { float x, y; } xy; // add member name, 
        struct { float r, g; } rg; // now the declaration declares a member 
        struct { float s, t; } st; // instead of an anonymous struct
    };
    vec2() {}
    vec2(float a, float b) : xy{a, b} {}
                          // ^^^^^^^^ also change the initialization
};

struct vec3
{
public:
    union
    {
        struct { float x, y, z; } xyz;     //
        struct { float r, g, b; } rgb;     //
        struct { float s, t, p; } stp;     // add member name
        struct { vec2 xy; float z; } vecz; //
        struct { float x; vec2 yz; } xvec; //
    };
    vec3() {}
    vec3(float a, float b, float c) : xyz{a, b, c} {}
                                   // ^^^^^^^^ also change the initialization
};
```

Now the code compiles under GCC, but that's not enough. Under Clang with `-pedantic-errors`, you'll get [several errors](https://godbolt.org/g/L5nU4L):

```
error: anonymous types declared in an anonymous union are an extension [-Werror,-Wnested-anon-types]
```

This is because you cannot declare a nested type in an anonymous union, so you should also move these struct definitions outside the union:

```
struct vec2
{
    struct XY { float x, y; };
    struct RG { float r, g; };
    struct ST { float s, t; };
    union
    {
        XY xy; 
        RG rg; 
        ST st; 
    };
    vec2() {}
    vec2(float a, float b) : xy{a, b} {}
};

struct vec3
{
    struct XYZ { float x, y, z; };     
    struct RGB { float r, g, b; };     
    struct STP { float s, t, p; };     
    struct VECZ { vec2 xy; float z; }; 
    struct XVEC { float x; vec2 yz; }; 
    union
    {
        XYZ xyz;     
        RGB rgb;     
        STP stp;     
        VECZ vecz; 
        XVEC xvec; 
    };
    vec3() {}
    vec3(float a, float b, float c) : xyz{a, b, c} {}
};
```

Although this solution works, you can only access the members via, for example, `v.xy.x`, instead of simple `v.x`. In addition, aliasing `vec2` with two `float`s would result in undefined behavior. I think there is no standard solution to achieve vector swizzling perfectly.

For non-standard solution, one can use a proxy class without constructors instead of `vec2` to make the compiler work. The [GLM library](https://github.com/g-truc/glm) also uses this idea. OP has already posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51822107/5376789) as a complete implementation of this idea.

Comment: I should make them anonymous to work as expected. It didn't work with the example provided in this post. The problem is with only constructors, not the whole variables. Actually, I don't know much about C++17, How can `std::variant` achieve this?.

Answer (score 2):

As for *"member with constructor not allowed in anonymous aggregate"*, , is due to compiler running in compliance with older standard, because [as of C++11, unions can have members with non-trivial constructors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Unrestricted_unions) (you defined your own constructor, so it's non-trivial, details about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899223/what-is-a-non-trivial-constructor-in-c)). Add -std=c++11 in your g++ compiler's arguments and this error will likely be gone.

Next. The only flags for g++ that could **maybe** make it compile your code are *-fms-extensions* and *-fvisibility-ms-compat*. Anonymous structs are a *non-standard* extension that Microsoft added to their compiler. Sorry, right now I can't test it, but I think that would do the trick.

And now some extras.

1. Unlike in C, you shouldn't `typedef` structs in C++ — if you named your structs, you can refer to them using that name as type.
2. Structs are public by default, no need in `public` here. Classes, however, are private by default.
3. If your intent is to just be able to use GLSL math in C++, [GLM](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) is the way to do it. If you want to learn how to do it yourself you can refer to their source code (it is quite heavy with templates, though).
4. Other g++ options can be found [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++).

Hope that this will help you at least somehow.

Comment: I already have my complete GLSL math library and it's faster, way better than GLM with *extras* and more GLSL-like, I was switching between struct and class definitions to debug the problem so I don't need to type `public:` every time, *forgot to remove it*. By the way, none of these command-lines worked. GLM itself doesn't support that feature. What makes my library more GLSL-like is that it has this feature so I've to fix it for all compilers or just let go it exactly as GLM did for the sake of the cross-platform compatibility... any other solution?

Comment: Here (https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/manual.md#section2) they say that for GLM will support swizzling if GLM_FORCE_SWIZZLE is defined before any other GLM file, and I really remember it working for me, but I used it on MSVC only. It has some quirks, which all detailed in the link I provided.
About question, I sorry, I can't really help now if those flags didn't helped.

Comment: Woow! I didn't know that it can do it. Also, it compiles fine in any compiler without any flags... I'll try to look into the source code and understand how it works. Thanks a lot!