# How to update multiple fields of a struct simultaneously?

Tags: c++, struct, field, accessor

Let's say I have a struct

```
struct Vector3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

Note that `sizeof(Vector3)` must remain the same.

EDIT: I am interested in solutions without setters.

Not let's create an instance of that struct `Vector3 pos` . How can I implement my struct so I can have something like this `pos.xy = 10 // updates x and y` or `pos.yz = 20 // updates y and z` or `pos.xz = 30 // updates x and z`?

Comment: you can do that but it needs lots of boilerplate, cant you use methods? `pos.set_yz(20)` ? Would that answer your quesiton or are you specifically looking for `pos.yz = 20;` ?

Comment: What would `pos.xy = 10` mean? `pos.x = pos.y = 10`?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yeah there is a solution with accessors, but I wanted to know whether there was without them... what do you mean by saying boilerplate?? Note: `sizeof(Vector3)` must remain the same.

Comment: @PiCTo exactly.

Comment: You can't do anything like this. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: boilerplate is code that you need to write to achieve something, but it serves no other purpose, it isnt nice code, the only reason to write it is because you want to achieve something that you cannot achieve more easily

Comment: This looks something like what is called swizzling. You can see an implementation of this in the GLM library.

Comment: Glm doesn't have swizzling either. It has some fancy functions to approximate it, but nothing like glsl's swizzles. And I strongly doubt swizzles in C++ would be possible without functions, macros or compiler support for this feature.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos Yeah the idea of doing this came from writing OpenGL shaders... I just need to overload some more operators for my struct, that's why I need to create a new one

Comment: @churill: See GLM_CONFIG_SWIZZLE ... https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/_swizzle.hpp https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/master/glm/detail/type_vec4.hpp

Comment: @AndrewTomazos this code is interesting, actually in the code you mentioned this generates 3! possible structs... or have I got something wrong?

Comment: @HrantNurijanyan: I think so, haven't looked at it closely for a while sorry.

Comment: I thnik my question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641131/how-to-achieve-vector-swizzling-in-c

Comment: See also: https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.1/api/a00002.html

Comment: To anyone who might want to close as duplicate, please find a way to merge the answers. Note that they aren't exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your type is standard-layout, I think the only *legal* way to do this, as per the C++ standard, is with a `union` that contains sub-objects with custom `operator=` definitions.

With a `union`, you're allowed to view the **common-initial sequence** of the active member, provided all types are standard-layout types. So if we carefully craft an object that shares the same common members (e.g. 3 `float` objects in the same order), then we can "swizzle" between them without violating strict-aliasing.

For us to accomplish this, we will need to create a bunch of members that all have the same data in the same order, in standard-layout type.

As a simple example, lets create a basic proxy type:

```cpp
template <int...Idx>
class Vector3Proxy
{
public:

    // ...

    template <int...UIdx, 
              typename = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Idx)==sizeof...(UIdx))>>
    auto operator=(const Vector3Proxy<UIdx...>& other) -> Vector3Proxy&
    {
        ((m_data[Idx] = other.m_data[UIdx]),...);
        return (*this);
    }

    auto operator=(float x) -> Vector3Proxy&
    {
        ((m_data[Idx] = x),...);
        return (*this);
    }

    // ...

private:

    float m_data[3];
    template <int...> friend class Vector3Proxy;
};
```

In this example, not all members of `m_data` are used -- but they exist so that the "common-initial sequence" requirement is satisfied, which will allow us to view it through other standard-layout types within the `union`.

This can be built up as much as you need; `float` conversion for single-component operators, support for arithmetic, etc.

With a type like this, we can now build a `Vector3` objects out of these proxy types

```cpp
struct Vector3
{
    union {
        float _storage[3]; // for easy initialization
        Vector3Proxy<0> x;
        Vector3Proxy<1> y;
        Vector3Proxy<2> z;
        Vector3Proxy<0,1> xy;
        Vector3Proxy<1,2> yz;
        Vector3Proxy<0,2> xz;
        // ...
    };
};
```

Then the type can easily be used to assign to multiple values at once:

```cpp
Vector3 x = {1,2,3};

x.xy = 5;
```

Or to assign components of one part to another:

```cpp
Vector3 a = {1,2,3};
Vector3 b = {4,5,6};

a.xy = b.yz; // produces {5,6,3}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/ErfT1M)</kbd>

This solution also ensures that `sizeof(Vector3)` does not change, since all proxy objects are the same size.

---

**Note:** It's not valid in C++ to use a `union` with anonymous `struct`s, though some compilers support it. So although it might be tempting to rewrite this like:

```cpp
union {
    struct {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;
    }; // invalid, since this is anonymous
    struct {
        ...
    } xy;
}
```

This is not valid in standard C++, and would not be a portable solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that has the desired syntax, and doesn't increase the size of the class. It is technically correct, but rather convoluted:

```
union Vector3 {
    struct {
        float x, y, z;
        auto& operator=(float f) { x = f; return *this; }
        operator       float&() &        { return  x; }
        operator const float&() const &  { return  x; }
        operator       float () &&       { return  x; }
        float* operator&()               { return &x; }
    } x;
    
    struct {
        float x, y, z;
        auto& operator=(float f) { y = f; return *this; }
        operator       float&() &        { return  y; }
        operator const float&() const &  { return  y; }
        operator       float () &&       { return  y; }
        float* operator&()               { return &y; }
    } y;
    
    struct {
        float x, y, z;
        auto& operator=(float f) { z = f; return *this; }
        operator       float&() &        { return  z; }
        operator const float&() const &  { return  z; }
        operator       float () &&       { return  z; }
        float* operator&()               { return &z; }
    } z;
    
    struct {
        float x, y, z;
        auto& operator=(float f) { x = y = f; return *this; }
    } xy;
    
    struct {
        float x, y, z;
        auto& operator=(float f) { y = z = f; return *this; }
    } yz;
    
    struct {
        float x, y, z;
        auto& operator=(float f) { z = x = f; return *this; }
    } zx;
};
```

---

Another which relies on `owner_of` implemented here: https://gist.github.com/xymopen/352cbb55ddc2a767ed7c5999cfed4d31 which probably depends on some technically implementation specific (possibly undefined) behaviour:

```
struct Vector3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    
    [[no_unique_address]]
    struct {
        auto& operator=(float f) {
            Vector3* v = owner_of(this, &Vector3::xy);
            v->x = v->y = f;
            return *this;
        }
    } xy;
    [[no_unique_address]]
    struct {
        auto& operator=(float f) {
            Vector3* v = owner_of(this, &Vector3::yz);
            v->y = v->z = f;
            return *this;
        } 
    } yz;
    [[no_unique_address]]
    struct {
        auto& operator=(float f) {
            Vector3* v = owner_of(this, &Vector3::zx);
            v->z = v->x = f;
            return *this;
        }
    } zx;
    [[no_unique_address]]
    struct {
        auto& operator=(float f) {
            Vector3* v = owner_of(this, &Vector3::zx);
            v->x = v->y = v->z = f;
            return *this;
        }
    } xyz;
};
```

Comment: In your link `offset_of` is undefined behavior (uses derefence of null), and also `reinterpret_cast`'s member pointers to integral values (which I believe violates any valid casts in the C++ language). I don't think any solution based on `owner_of` is valid in C++, even if "it works:"

Comment: Oh, you had the same idea as I had :)

Comment: @Human-Compiler Except that the indirection is within an addressof operator and is therefore not evaluated. It's true that the defect [issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#232) regarding this is still unresolved.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way is to provide setters for the combinations you want to set:

```
struct Vector3 {
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
    void set_xy(float v) {
        x = v;
        y = v;
    }
};

int main(){
    Vector3 pos;
    pos.set_xy(42);
}
```

And if you need `sizeof(Vector3)` to stay the same, thats the only way.

---

Just "for fun" this is how you can get `pos.set_xy = 20;` literally:

```
struct two_setter {
    float& one;    
    float& two;
    void operator=(float v){
        one = v;
        two = v;
    }
};

struct Vector3 {
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
    two_setter set_xy{x,y};
};

int main(){
    Vector3 pos;
    pos.set_xy = 42;
}
```

However, it has severe downsides. First it can have almost twice the size of the original `Vector3`. Moreover, because the `two_setter` stores references, `Vector3` cannot be copied. If it would store pointers, copying would be possible, but then even more code would be required to get it right.

Alternatively it is possible to provide a `xy` method that returns a proxy that assigns the two members. But I am not going into detail, because `pos.xy() = 3;` looks really odd, has no advantage to `pos.xy(3)` and you really should provide a setter (or just rely on the user making two assignments when they want to make two assignments ;).

*TL;DR* Use a method instead of trying to get a syntax that C++ does not support out of the box.

Comment: It would be a sad thing to have `Vector3` that large in size.

Comment: @Evg agree. It was just to show a way how it can be done in principle, because OP seems to be asking only out of curiosity, maybe I should be more clear about the "don't do it"

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create an empty struct inside `Vector3` with an `operator=()` that sets the variables of the outer struct. Of course for a variable to really take no space itself, you have to use `[[no_unique_address]]`, which is only available since C++20. But here is an example of how it might work:

```
struct Vector3 {
    [[no_unique_address]] struct {
        auto &operator=(float val) {
            Vector3 *self = (Vector3 *)(this);
            self->x = val;
            self->y = val;
            return *this;
        }
    } xy;

    // Add similar code for xz and yz

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

See it running on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tLgDZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEQkyaQAOqBYXVaPUMTcx8/ALpbeycjV3dPRWVMVUCGAmZiAmDjU04LJRU1OnTMgmjHFzcPLwUMrJzQ/MV68rtKuOrPAEpFVANiZA4AcikAZjtkQywAanExnXU64kxmI3nscQAGAEFtneWDVRmANRSiYjG5gHZZXZmHuYBWWRfaVAB9A1o8AEcDTAfZjodArBQKcRPAAikKhM0Ox3Et32j1Rp3OJCuUjMqG8bmYF3mUOorFQBJmADc2N0bncdmiGejVJiZgAqQpUOZjOErOwENzeFYED4sOrzHRnZmXNkbCAEBB4BTdeZ0xlojkAWg2AA8uXCqawVSi1Y9NRsAJ56ylsI33E0PIUDWhsjm2%2BmMpEwu0PT0zbXmt3Gh5UUnk7Vu1EhskEGYBsaqx5R8kAL0D1xh8f2%2Bz5MyMzDsEBpSITD0lFyuFJSYwjj0ryDGADpdUSZpwaw8643LS3JO3KVWG8mrdXM97%2B/Wm93uTNuL3R%2B6HnV0CAUP0Y%2BLxePG82FpupF45p4uTpN52G1OTwtDwf98fTwOhxur/vITpaC/557hr1WCBhk9hlIUxhi2QDUD/E8ZDkeF%2BkGTBDzGThAIIP9QO6XoAGsQDGRscLw/CCIsX9hm4QDgNA0hwOGQCFBALZSBQkDv1IOBYCQNAjG8PB2DICgIA4rieJAYAFFoZhvAUBBUAIUgqG4/liFoiBnFQwDnDsTJzVU0gOKMLQCAAeVoVgtKY0gsDzUR2D/JDzLwFZUkrWizMwbUUgMfltL5ZQbMA1g8GcYhNL0LBfIY4g8CMXzehoegmDYDgeH4QRhFEFA5DkIQAtoyBelxYpaGcjUDMkGYNQAdTYVgyvKsqlyJCQoJkSQKMKc5Ak0bRGjySxtAqWJ4kEXx/AK7qhoiAr%2BqqdxOCSIo0laMbZra1ISlaKbOhmloyiW7asg2wbOF6BRYKGLgfz/ACgO0qjtQADjMDUzG4GZgGQZAZjlYhvgwmkIFwQgSAQ2aZj0TjuLcYGaUg2QZGQ1T0NILCcIbAi0bwoi/1I66zKomi6IYhGWJgRAQDXbwPPISgBIhrbMHwC5BFixgWGspKAHcgu8aKhEusibr/cZOBmdnCAQP0Hqel63o%2Br6fu6eGmMR5HcPRtHeZI/ncb/fH6MYtCLuGSQtYovHCaV3pK0UjruCAA%3D).

Comment: Maybe I can union them somehow, without using [[no_unique_address]]?

Comment: Is it valid to alias a member sub-object to the containing type? I know the inverse is true (you can `reinterpret_cast` a `foo` to `foo`'s first member), but I think this cast is technically undefined behavior

Comment: Something like this `union { struct {(Your struct); z}; struct { float x; float y; float z}};`

Comment: Yeap reinterpret_cast will work badly for your answer, but technically this is an answer)

Comment: @HrantNurijanyan anonymous `struct`s in unions don't exist in C++ (as your code example has). This would only work through compiler extensions, but is technically not valid code. However, there may still be a valid approach using `union`s

Comment: @Human-Compiler I'm not sure actually, but it seems like both GCC and Clang do seem to recognize that I'm aliasing the types, and calculate the expected output at compile time, see [this godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/frYTMz).

Comment: @Human-Compiler If anonymous structs inside the `union` don't work, you can still have a named struct holding the actual values, but then you just have to create single variable "swizzle" operators for `x`, `y` and `z` :)

Comment: @G.Sliepen Unfortunately, the compiler (or multiple compilers) producing the correct result does not mean that the solution is well-defined by the standard, or guaranteed to continue working on different compilers, optimization levels, etc. Compilers often let you alias things as an extension since a lot of valid C code can't be compiled otherwise. To your second point on Swizzling: that's what I think would need to be done as the only valid (per language spec) solution for this problem... A union of proxy types with the same common initial sequence

Comment: @Human-Compiler I agree it looks shady, however, GCC normally is very agressive with aliasing rules, and even if I hide the definition of `xy::operator=()` from the compiler, it seems to think it might change other member variables, see [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/sP7szW). Maybe there is some rule in the standard that makes this work after all?

Comment: It is allowed to cast between such pointers if the struct has standard layout. Aliasing does not play a role here, since there really is a `Vector3` object living at that address.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I implement my struct so I can have something like this `pos.xy = 10 // updates x and y` or `pos.yz = 20 // updates y and z` or `pos.xz = 30 // updates x and z`?

Just add the necessary class member functions to do this:

```
struct Vector3 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    void update_xy(float value) { x = y = value; }
    void update_yz(float value) { y = z = value; }
    void update_xz(float value) { x = z = value; }
};
```

Comment: Yeah there is a solution with accessors I was interested whether there is one without them?

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: @HrantNurijanyan As _@Sam_ mentioned, there's no other way to do this. What's the problem with this though? Are you asking how to solve a [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/xy-problem/info)? Can you edit yoir question and elaborate about your specific use case please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No I am just curious can something like this be achieved)